# How to center an image in a column in an ExtJS GridPanel?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I would like to **horizontally center** the icon in the column "Data":

[image]

I've got **textAlign: center** on my column:

[image]

And in the icon renderer function, I'm horizontally centering it with **CSS**:

[image]

Yet it is still left-aligned.

**What else do I have to do so that the icon in the column is centered horizontally?**

Comment: can you give me the complete renderDataIcon function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess, because I don't have anything to test.

I notice that `margin: 0 auto` isn't working to center the image.

This leads me to think that you need `display: block` on the image - that should let your `margin` rule do what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Adding align: 'center' to the actioncolumn item did the trick, like so:

```js
{
   xtype: 'actioncolumn',
   text: 'Edit',
   align: 'center',
   items: [{**}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to change the render function like this:

```
function renderDataIcon(val) {
    if(val=='online') {
        return '<div style="width:100%;height:16px;background-image:url(/images/icon_yellow_dot.png);background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>';
    } else {
        return '<div style="width:100%;height:16px;background-image:url(/images/icon_red_dot.png);background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;">&nbsp;</div>';
    }
}
```